# Get branch name in build step

Tags: teamcity

I am using Teamcity to build docker builds and I want to use the git branch in build steps. I create a build within a project, I then create a build step in that build to do a docker push and I set the image name:tag to `registry:5000/myproject/%maven.project.artifactId%:%teamcity.build.branch%`

When I run the build, it just queues and nothing happens. There is a message saying:

> Implicit requirements: teamcity.build.branch defined in Build step: Docker push

How can I get the git branch so that I can use the branch name in the docker label:tag?